# accessing non static variables from another project reference (C# and VB)

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, reference, monogame

This is my first post on stack overflow so please excuse anything I've done wrong.
I have two projects under the same solution in visual studio, a form in VB and a simulation using a monogame game engine in c#. The VB form is being used as a data display where I am showing a line graph of data. I have referenced the c# simulation in the VB form so I can get the data across from one to the other but it is only allowing me to view static variables, is there any way that I can view lists and other variables that are dynamically changing from another project.

Here is the code for the form in vb.

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting
Imports Evolution_Simulator

Public Class Form1
    Public meanGenerationDistances As New Series

    'sets a variable to the number of lines
    Dim numOfVariables As Integer = Evolution_Simulator.Game1.distances.Count
    Dim testNumberOfVars As Integer


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'list for data
        Dim ListOfMeansOfEachGeneration As New List(Of Integer)
        Dim counter As Integer = 0


        'changes the title of chart
        Chart1.Titles.Add("Creature Distances")

        'creates a new line on the graph
        meanGenerationDistances.Name = "Mean Distances of each generation"
        'sets it as a line graph
        meanGenerationDistances.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line

        'removes series1 lable from graph
        Chart1.Series.Clear()

        Chart1.Series.Add(meanGenerationDistances)

        'starts the timer
        Timer1.Start()

    End Sub

    'sub to add to the graph
    Sub addToGraph(ByVal toAdd As Integer)
        meanGenerationDistances.Points.Add(toAdd)
    End Sub


    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        Console.WriteLine("NUM                                                  " & numOfVariables)
        Console.WriteLine("EVOL                                                 " & Evolution_Simulator.Game1.distances.Count)

        addToGraph(1)

        'checks to see if a new item has been added to the list
        If Evolution_Simulator.Game1.distances.Count > numOfVariables Then
            numOfVariables = Evolution_Simulator.Game1.distances.Count
            addToGraph(Game1.distances(numOfVariables))
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the code for the class that is being referenced, it is in another project but under the same solution

```cs
using Evolution_Simulator.Sprites;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Evolution_Simulator
{     

    public class Game1 : Game
    {


        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        #region variables

        //used for pre-set values of screen width and height
        public static int screenHeight;
        public static int screenWidth;

        //allows the game to make a random value
        public static Random random;

        //gametimer for generating new things
        private double _timer;

        //bool for stating whether or not a game has started
        private bool _hasStarted = false;           

        //variable for the test creature I will be using until i generate 1000 of them
        public Creature creature;

        //creates an array which stores the results of all the creatures
        public Creature[] creatureArray = new Creature[50];

        //counter for adding to array
        int counter = 0;

        //could use a queue later for more a-level content
        //static list of all distances of the creatures 
        public static List<double> distances = new List<double>();

        #endregion



        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

            //initialises the random object
            random = new Random();            

            //sets the size of the window
            screenWidth = graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth;
            screenHeight = graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight;
        }

        protected override void Initialize()        {


            base.Initialize();
        }


        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            //sets the texture for the node
            var nodeTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("node");


            //instantiates the creature, assigning it a nodeTexture
            creature = new Creature(nodeTexture);

            //loops through each node that has been generated
            creature.createNodes(nodeTexture);           

        }


        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {

        }


        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            //starts the sim if space is pressed
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
            {
                _hasStarted = true;
            }

            //makes sure nothing happens when space is pressed
            if (!_hasStarted)
            {
                return;
            }


            //incriments the timer
            _timer = _timer + gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

            //lets a creature run for 15 seconds
            if (_timer <= 15)
            {
                //updates all of the creatures logic
                //such as node positions, muscle contractions etc...
                creature.Update(gameTime);
            }
            else if(_timer > 15)
            {
                if (counter > creatureArray.Length - 1)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    //resets timer
                    _timer = 0;
                    //adds creature to array, will be sorted later
                    creatureArray[counter] = creature;

                    //loops through each node to get mean distance travelled
                    foreach (var node in creature.nodes)
                    {
                        creature.distanceTravelled = creature.distanceTravelled + node.position.X;
                    }
                    creature.distanceTravelled = creature.distanceTravelled / creature.numberOfnodes;

                    //incriment the counter
                    counter++;

                    //adds the distance travelled by the creature to the list
                    distances.Add(creature.distanceTravelled);

                    Console.WriteLine("DISTANCES                                                    " + distances.Count.ToString());

                    LoadContent();
                }

            }          

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }


        private void FileWrite(float toWrite, int counter)
        {      

            //writes to a file called "data"
            //file is cleared in the windows form so not needed here
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter((@"E:\Cameron Duff Computer Science NEA\Windows Form Data Display\Data display for project\Data display for project\bin\Debug\data.txt"), true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(toWrite);
            }

        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.DarkBlue);
            spriteBatch.Begin();


            //draws all of the sprites, i.e. nodes
            creature.Draw(spriteBatch);


            spriteBatch.End();
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes.  You need to add other project dll as a reference using Add Existing Item.  Then add using (or import) statement on top of module with names space of dll.  Then use an Instance of the class object.

Comment: @jdweng OP did add a reference from the VB to C# project already - and your method for adding a reference directly to the dll when you can add a project reference is not recommended in most cases. The reference should probably be added by right clicking References >> Add Reference > Project.

Comment: You should provide some C# code showing which variables you're talking about. If they are instance members of some class then you will need a reference to an instance of that class. Static variables are easier to access but generally not advisable.

Comment: Ok but your code isn't valid. The static list isn't declared right next to a foreach loop. Show the namespace and classes too so we can see exactly what you are doing.

Comment: okay, thank you guys for your time @djv inparticular, I've added the main class that everything is being referenced from and also the code for the windows form. The form is just made up of a chart and that's it. Thanks again guys

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, we still don't have the full picture even with all the code you've provided. So I'll give you some options.

1. If the instance can be created in the VB code. Use a readonly property with lazy-loading. (Instantiation can be forced at any time by accessing the property). But it must be created at the VB level.

```vb
Private ReadOnly Property MyGame1 As Game1
    Get
        Static instance As Game1
        If instance Is Nothing Then instance = New Game1()
        Return instance
    End Get
End Property

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Console.WriteLine($"{"EVOL".PadRight(53)}{MyGame1.distances.Count()}")
    ' ...
End Sub
```

2. The Game1 class could be a singleton. The instantiation is done in the C# but only one instance is allowed.

```
private Game1() { }

private static Game1 instance;

public static Game1 GetInstance()
{
    if (instance == null) instance = new Game1();
    return instance;
}
```

```vb
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Console.WriteLine($"{"EVOL".PadRight(53)}{Game1.GetInstance().distances.Count()}")
    ' ...
End Sub
```

3. You use a factory to create the instance, outside of both classes you've provided. (The factory is greatly simplified and typically would return a less derived class than Game1)

```cs
public static class Factory
{
    private static Game1 instance;

    public static Game1 GetGame1()
    {
        if (instance == null) instance = new Game1();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

```vb
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Console.WriteLine($"{"EVOL".PadRight(53)}{Factory.GetGame1().distances.Count}")
    ' ...
End Sub
```

4. The instantiation is done elsewhere, such as Program.cs or Form1.vb etc. and we don't have enough information, still. You'll need to pass the instance around somehow. In no case should `distances` be static.